# AppCache works fine with Firefox (30) but not with IE (11)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm trying to provide an offline version of my asp.net website. So if i call my Default page it should load the offline.html. In Firefox its working, in IE (11 and i tested 10 in Emulation mode) not.

***Manifest.appcache***

```
CACHE MANIFEST
 # version 1

CACHE:
offline.html

NETWORK:

FALLBACK:
Default offline.html
```

***Web.config***

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".appcache" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".appcache" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" />
</staticContent>
```

***Default***

```
<html manifest="Manifest.appcache">
```

Also there is a "Fatal error of "AppCache"." in IE.

Any ideas or alternatives for IE?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that can cause issues with appcache; it can be tricky to set up, and then debugging it can be a royal pain because the browsers just don't give much in the way of useful information about why it's gone wrong.

It has lots of gotchas, including several nasty cross-browser quirks (which affect all the major browsers; testing is important).

The main cross-browser quirk that causes it to fails in IE when it works in other browsers is if you've forgotten to set the mime type of the manifest file.

Set the mime type as follows:

```
text/cache-manifest
```

IE can be picky about that where the other browsers aren't. This is because the spec has changed relatively recently; previously the mime type was listed as mandatory; that requirement has been dropped from the spec because most browsers didn't enforce it, but IE did and still does enforce it.

So set the mime type, and hopefully that should sort things out.

Comment: Where should i set the mime type? In Web.config isn't enough?